# Removing a directory from routing path in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I relocated my app from a subdirectory to thee root by changing the baseHref but now I want to make sure that links which refer to http://myapp.com/subirectory/someitem/42/subitem/27 are correctly redirected to http://myapp.com/someitem/42/subitem/27

My app-routing.module.ts looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'subdirectory/:therest', redirectTo: '/:therest' },
    { path: 'subdirectory', redirectTo: '/' },
    { path: 'someitem', loadChildren: 'app/items/items.module#ItemsModule' },
    { path: 'otheritem', loadChildren: 'app/foo/foo.module#FooModule' },
];
```

This only works up to the point where *therest* contains another parameter, which should be handled by ItemsRoutingModule.

How can I change my routing module, so that the subdirectory part is removed, but the rest of the url is preserved? Do I have to set up the redirect for every single route of my application?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [redirects](https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects). In your case something in the lines of:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'someitem/:id/subitem/:subid',        component: YourComponent },
  { path: 'subirectory/someitem/:id/subitem/:subid',   redirectTo: '/someitem/:subid/subitem/:id', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a redirect which just removes the subdirectory (independent of how deep the route is divided afterwards) or do I have to add redirects for every route (since the routes are nested, there are quite a few)

Comment: Remove `pathMatch: 'full'`, it will handle all matching and nested routes.

Comment: I actually want to have the whole part `someitem/:id/subitem/:subid` as one parameter which is handled by another route without the subdirectory. I added my Routes as code in the question.